# How can I remove the rounded edges and transparent border from a metacity theme?

Tags: themes, metacity

I have a problem with my current theme. When windows top border close to top panel, there's a transparent background at the top corner (please take a look at the attached image).

[image]

So, how could I :

- remove it?
- change the rounded corners (I love the less rounded corners - like MAC OS X)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To change the corners, you will have to edit the theme, or choose a different one. Also, you should ensure compositing is enabled, if you want rounded corners. You can do this by using compiz instead, or by running `gconf-editor`, opening the `/apps/metacity/general` item in the tree, and enabling the `compositor_effects` option in the list on the right. With that on, you should not see this artifact in the theme.